# These commands do not generate de fle .ind

Tags: makeindex

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}%
\usepackage{amsfonts}%
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{Index}
\include{Chapters/Chapter_01}
\include{Chapters/Chapter_02}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to SE. Please make an effort to write a question that can be understood. Explain what your problem is, format your LaTeX code properly using the tools of this site and, if applicable, show the error log.

Comment: We don't have those files (Chapter_01.tex,Chapter_02.tex). Please make you code complete. Take a look this: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that